# is it wise to make every class loaded automatically

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

i'm programming an MVC and i need an advice, is it wise to make every class loaded automatically including controllers,models ,core classes using spl_autoload_register or this may make issues or a slow performance.

Answer (score 1):

This probably depends on many factors, but I have used frameworks where I load every class automatically (from a relatively large autload function that looks in broad places) as well as a *lot* of nested includes.  I have never noticed a performance problem with autoloading like that at all.  It makes things significantly simpler since you don't have to worry about includes conflicting either.

As I said, though, it may depend.  It's up to you to test out which method is faster with benchmarking.  If you have a preferred method in terms of implementation that is slower, you will have to make the decision of whether or not the speed difference is enough to use an inferior but faster implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases - Yes, it is. Loading classes manually as you guess will increase performance, but a little and only in that cases where you have, for example, a library that consist from a lot of files (PHPExcel for example), but even in this cases it's more preferable to use Autoload.

In total: in most cases (especially for conventional sites) manual loading is micro-optimization.

The best way to deal with this feature - launch a benchmark if it seems that the performance drops a problem. The benchmark is the best way because all depends on the architecture framework

Comment: I don't want to say you are wrong, but many developers have reported that taking the time to switch from manual loading to autoloading offers a measurable performance *boost*.  You get the advantage of not having to use *`_once` and not including what you don't need.

Comment: autloading will do that for you it's not gonna load what you don't need so that's cool

Comment: Autoloading will load new code in the current global scope and will have to parse it and compare it for conflicts with existing defined classes/functions/constants. Doing this at runtime in the middle of script execution might result in fatal errors (while require_once would have prevented the script from running) and because such checks aren't done all at once, autoloading will degrade performance.